# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'useNativeDriver') with Expo animation

Tags: react-native, expo

I have that code :

```
export default function Shimmer() {
  const AnimatedView = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(LinearGradient);
  const animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0);
  const translateX = animatedValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [-width, width],
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.loop(
      Animated.timing(
        (animatedValue,
        {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 1000,
          easing: Easing.linear,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        })
      )
    ).start();
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.backgroundView}>
        <AnimatedView
          colors={["#a0a0a0", "#b0b0b0", "#b0b0b0", "#a0a0a0"]}
          start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
          end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}
          style={[
            StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
            {
              transform: [{ translateX: translateX }],
            },
          ]}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I would like to make a shimmer effect like shown in this video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPwa0WMAH8A

I have set useNativeDriver to true, but I get this error :

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'useNativeDriver')
```

How can I fix that (I am working with Expo) ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by removing a parenthesis here :

```
 Animated.loop(
      Animated.timing(
        animatedValue,
        {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 1000,
          easing: Easing.linear,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }
      )
    ).start();
  });
```